# Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ",")
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1) latitude
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",2),",",-1) longitude
     , ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.2734487789) ) * cos( radians(latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(10.5438383386) ) + sin( radians(52.2734487789) ) * sin( radians(latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM `wp_umkreissuche_posts` AS posts
     ,  `wp_umkreissuche_postmeta` AS postmeta 
 WHERE posts.post_type = "adresses" 
   AND posts.ID=postmeta.post_id 
   AND postmeta.meta_key="latitude" 
    OR posts.post_type="adresses" 
   AND posts.ID=postmeta.post_id 
   AND postmeta.meta_key="longitude" 
 GROUP 
    BY postmeta.post_id 
HAVING distance < 0.5 
 ORDER 
    BY postmeta.post_id
     ,  distance ASC
```

Comment: provide more information

Comment: i think your table does not contains a field name 'latitude'..please confirm!!

Comment: Start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd start with the OR. You need to clarify your intent there. parentheses can help with that. Also, to my mind, there is almost no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) is the solution.

Comment: And as artista says, you need to replace references to latitude with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, formatted a bit better and with clearer `join` syntax:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","), 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1) AS latitude, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",2),",",-1) AS longitude,
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.2734487789) ) * cos( radians(latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(10.5438383386) ) + sin( radians(52.2734487789) ) * sin( radians(latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `wp_umkreissuche_posts` AS posts JOIN
     `wp_umkreissuche_postmeta` AS postmeta
     ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND posts.post_type = 'adresses' AND
        (postmeta.meta_key IN ('latitude', 'longitude')
        )
GROUP BY postmeta.post_id
HAVING distance < 0.5
ORDER BY postmeta.post_id, distance ASC
```

Your direct problem is that `latitude` and `longitude` are defined in the `select`, so they cannot be used at the same select level.  The normal solution is to repeat the expression or to use a subquery, so the alias is known.  However, the logic for your query doesn't look write.  I suspect it should be something more like this:

```
SELECT CONCATE_WS, ',', lat.postmeta.meta_value, lng.postmeta.meta_value) ,
       lat.postmeta.meta_value AS latitude, 
       lng.meta_value AS longitude,
       . . .
FROM `wp_umkreissuche_posts` posts JOIN
     `wp_umkreissuche_postmeta` lat
     ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND posts.post_type = 'adresses' AND lat.meta_key = 'latitude' JOIN
     `wp_umkreissuche_postmeta` lng
     ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND posts.post_type = 'adresses' AND lng.meta_key = 'longitude' 
HAVING distance < 0.5
ORDER BY postmeta.post_id, distance ASC;
```

Note:  you *can* use the `having` without a `group by` in MySQL.  It then behaves like a `where` but it allows column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias name in another field in the same query unless you use a subquery or join.

Use

```
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1)
```

instead of `latitude`.

Try this way:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1) AS latitude,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",2),",",-1) AS longitude,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.2734487789) ) * cos( radians(latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(10.5438383386) ) + sin( radians(52.2734487789) ) * sin( radians((SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(postmeta.meta_value) SEPARATOR ","),",",1)) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM wp_umkreissuche_posts AS posts, wp_umkreissuche_postmeta AS postmeta 
WHERE posts.post_type="adresses" AND posts.ID=postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key="latitude" OR posts.post_type="adresses" AND posts.ID=postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key="longitude" 
GROUP BY postmeta.post_id HAVING distance < 0.5 
ORDER BY postmeta.post_id, distance ASC
```